# How to change the dropdown position of the HTML5 audio player when CSS zoom is applied?

Tags: html, css, html5-audio

This issue happens in Chrome, Brave and even Internet Explorer/Edge:

When clicking the three dots to open the dropdown, the dropdown is far away from the audio player:

[image: html5 audio dropdown]

With Webdeveloper I cannot target the dropdown. It seems to be directly from the browser.

So how to change its position to be directly at the three dots of the HTML audio embed?

**Update:**

I found out that the issue is the CSS `zoom` that is used on the `audio` element:

```
audio {
    zoom: 80%;
}
```

This repositions the dropdown!

Sidenote:
The zoom is needed to present the audio embed in a proper porportion, so the audio timeline shows up wider. Due to the HTML layout on our site, the maximum width we can use is 250px.

Without zoom:

[image: audio embed without CSS zoom]

With zoom:

[image: audio embed with CSS zoom]

Summed up:

We need the zoom but it misplaces the dropdown. How to fix this? So the audio player dropdown is at the correct/default position.

Comment: As this appears to be a common browser bug, if you have to use `zoom`, I imagine your options are: Report a bug and wait for them to fix it, or use a custom audio player UI (Either by writing your own or finding an existing library)

Comment: So there is no CSS selector for the audio dropdown? Because that would be a solution.

Comment: No there isn't - most browser defaults don't. You can style the actual input and parts of it, but dropdowns are a system feature not a page feature. Like the default color or data picker. This is indeed a bug in the browsers. Annoying, but not something you should try to fight but should report. Because your solutions (not this one, this one seems fine) might break again when they fix it in the future.

Comment: Dude, I can see from your rating that you are not a newbie, so why are you choosing an answer that is a duplicate of mine? It's just really sad when I take my time to help and someone steals my answer and you choose it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the MDN webdocs [`zoom` is a non-standard feature and should't be used in production code](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/zoom).

The docs suggests to use `transform: scale()` instead. So you could use it like this:

```css
p {
  font-size: 2rem;
}

audio {
  width: 250px;
  height: 1em;
  margin: 0 -0.8em 0 -0.8em;
  transform: scale(80%);
  transform-origin: bottom;
}
```

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, conse do eiusmod aliqua. Ut enim ad minim, quis nostrud ullamco <audio controls src="https://github.com/rafaelreis-hotmart/Audio-Sample-files/raw/master/sample.mp3"
    controls></audio> laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.</p>
```

Note the audio height and margins are using `em` units that means they are relative to the parent `<p>` element.

Answer (score 0):

You can set `transform: scale(.8);` instead of the non-standardized `zoom: 80%;`.
If you need to compensate for empty space (since the dimensions of the element are preserved after applying `transform`), you can set a `margin`.
Somehow:

```css
audio {
  --scale: .8;
  --width: 350px;
  --height: 54px;
  transform: scale(var(--scale));
  transform-origin: left top;
  width: var(--width);
  height: var(--height);
  margin: 0 calc(var(--width) * var(--scale) - var(--width)) calc(var(--height) * var(--scale) - var(--height)) 0;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div>Lorem ipsum dolor.</div>
<audio src="/" controls></audio> <i>Audio info</i>
<div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</div>
```